# Selected Item in BottomNavigationView Has Same Color as Background

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, material-components, material-components-android, android-bottomnav

I am implementing a bottom navigation menu. but the first item in the menu is not selected. I notice that when I change the color of bar background then it shows, and the reason is that the first item "enabled" color is the same as the background color of my navbar. How can I change the colors of the enabled tab as well as the remaining items. By default they're black... let's say I want to change them to white. Thanks
image of main activity. http://pctechtips.org/apps/activity.png
menu xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_dashboard" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_notifications" />
</menu>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <org.techgeorge.textrecon.PaintView
        android:id="@+id/paintView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make drawable selector for your bottom navigation view, here is the example (nav_item_color_state.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/darker_gray" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

then add codes below to your bottom navigation view

> app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
>   app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"

Comment: Thanks, this really helped.

Answer (score 11):

The color of the selected/unselected icons and labels are defined by the **`app:itemIconTint`** and **`app:itemTextColor`** attributes with a selector.  The default style of the `BottomNavigationView` uses this selector for tinting the icon and the label of the icons:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="1.0" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.6" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

Check if for some reason the colors `colorOnSurface` and `colorPrimary` are the same color of the background of your `BottomNavigationView`.

You can in any case **override these colors without defining a new selector**.
Just use the **`android:theme`** attribute:

```
  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.BottomNavView"
      ../>
```

with:

```
  <style name="ThemeOverlay.BottomNavView" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/secondaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>
```

You can also use a custom style with the **`materialThemeOverlay`** attribute:

```
  <style name="MyWidget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.BottomNavView</item>
  </style>
```

with:

```
  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
      style="@style/MyWidget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView"
      ../>
```

This last attribute requires the version **1.1.0** of the library.

Comment: Very clear answer on how to do this via theming.

Comment: Wondering if this can also be overriden in the app's theme?